# Making separate variables for the "first" month's observation

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to ask for your guidance regarding making separate variables (columns) for the "first" month's observation of a value.

Specifically, by "first", it includes:

1. Groups' **first-observation-of-the-year** value
2. Groups' **first observation of the entire observations**

An example data looks like:

```
structure(list(Group = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3), Time = structure(c(4L, 
5L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 7L), .Label = c("2013-02-28", 
"2014-01-31", "2014-02-28", "2014-04-30", "2014-05-31", "2014-06-30", 
"2015-09-30", "2015-12-31", "2016-03-31", "2017-01-31"), class = "factor"), 
    Value = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.4, 0.5
    ), Firstobsoftheeyear = c(0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.2, 0.3, 
    0.4, 0.4, 0.5), Firstobs = c(0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 
    0.5, 0.5, 0.4, 0.4)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), codepage = 65001L)
```

And the end result would look like:

```
╔═══════╦════════════╦═══════╦═════════════════════════════════════╦═════════════════════════════════╗
║ Group ║ Time       ║ Value ║ First-observation-of-the-year value ║ Group's first observation value ║
╠═══════╬════════════╬═══════╬═════════════════════════════════════╬═════════════════════════════════╣
║ 1     ║ 2014-04-30 ║ 0.1   ║ 0.1                                 ║ 0.1                             ║
╠═══════╬════════════╬═══════╬═════════════════════════════════════╬═════════════════════════════════╣
║ 1     ║ 2014-05-31 ║ 0.2   ║ 0.1                                 ║ 0.1                             ║
╠═══════╬════════════╬═══════╬═════════════════════════════════════╬═════════════════════════════════╣
║ 1     ║ 2014-06-30 ║ 0.3   ║ 0.1                                 ║ 0.1                             ║
╠═══════╬════════════╬═══════╬═════════════════════════════════════╬═════════════════════════════════╣
║ 2     ║ 2014-01-31 ║ 0.5   ║ 0.5                                 ║ 0.5                             ║
╠═══════╬════════════╬═══════╬═════════════════════════════════════╬═════════════════════════════════╣
║ 2     ║ 2014-02-28 ║ 0.7   ║ 0.5                                 ║ 0.5                             ║
╠═══════╬════════════╬═══════╬═════════════════════════════════════╬═════════════════════════════════╣
║ 2     ║ 2015-12-31 ║ 0.2   ║ 0.2                                 ║ 0.5                             ║
╠═══════╬════════════╬═══════╬═════════════════════════════════════╬═════════════════════════════════╣
║ 2     ║ 2016-03-31 ║ 0.3   ║ 0.3                                 ║ 0.5                             ║
╠═══════╬════════════╬═══════╬═════════════════════════════════════╬═════════════════════════════════╣
║ 2     ║ 2017-01-31 ║ 0.4   ║ 0.4                                 ║ 0.5                             ║
╠═══════╬════════════╬═══════╬═════════════════════════════════════╬═════════════════════════════════╣
║ 3     ║ 2013-02-28 ║ 0.4   ║ 0.4                                 ║ 0.4                             ║
╠═══════╬════════════╬═══════╬═════════════════════════════════════╬═════════════════════════════════╣
║ 3     ║ 2015-09-30 ║ 0.5   ║ 0.5                                 ║ 0.4                             ║
╚═══════╩════════════╩═══════╩═════════════════════════════════════╩═════════════════════════════════╝
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can create a grouping on the `year` column and then get the `first` 'Value' based on the 'Group' and 'Year', then reset the grouping to only 'Group' and redo the `first` to create 'FirstObs' of 'Group'

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df1 %>% 
    group_by(Group, Year = year(as.Date(Time))) %>%
    mutate(FirstObsoftheyear = first(Value)) %>%
    group_by(Group) %>% 
    mutate(FirstObs = first(Value))
```

Answer (score 0):

In base R, you can do this with `ave` :

```
df$Time <- as.Date(df$Time)
df$Firstobsoftheeyear <- with(df, ave(Value, Group, format(Time, '%Y'), 
                                  FUN = function(x) x[1]))
df$Firstobs <- with(df, ave(Value, Group, FUN = function(x) x[1]))
df

#   Group       Time Value Firstobsoftheeyear Firstobs
#1      1 2014-04-30   0.1                0.1      0.1
#2      1 2014-05-31   0.2                0.1      0.1
#3      1 2014-06-30   0.3                0.1      0.1
#4      2 2014-01-31   0.5                0.5      0.5
#5      2 2014-02-28   0.7                0.5      0.5
#6      2 2015-12-31   0.2                0.2      0.5
#7      2 2016-03-31   0.3                0.3      0.5
#8      2 2017-01-31   0.4                0.4      0.5
#9      3 2013-02-28   0.4                0.4      0.4
#10     3 2015-09-30   0.5                0.5      0.4
```